# Encoding a live stream of bitmaps using FFMPEG

Tags: c#, video, bitmap, ffmpeg, encode

I've got a constant stream of jpeg's that need to be converted to a video (of any kind).
The problem is that the stream is virtually infinite and I don't know any method of creating videos using pictures that doesn't store the whole file in memory until the stream stops..

Is there a way that I can feed FFMPEG with bitmaps or jpegs constantly from c# or at least make ffmpeg read images from a folder with +432000 images (on the command line)?

Please note that there will be no sound, the images will be low quality, they will come at a rate ~5 FPS and this will run on a high-ish end laptop. BTW I can provide code but I assume this is unnecessary at the moment as I am only creating bitmaps and saving them.

Comment: @RandomUser Because this is supposed to be a surveillance camera application and it will record video 24 hours long at a frame rate of 5 fps. 24*60*60* 5 = 432000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
You could create an `MJPEG` stream based on the static images.

Here's a sample project written in node:

https://github.com/psanford/node-mjpeg-test-server/tree/master/resources

It would be preferable to configure the source to send MJPEG directly if possible. You could then use this stream as input and live transcode it to something else.

**Command line:**

From the command line you can use `-pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg'` or `-i img%06d.jpg` if your files are sequential like img000000.jpg, img000001.jpg etc.

Source and examples: [FFmpeg - Create a video slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

Comment: I tried that but FFMPEG encodes the video faster than my program saves them hence ffmpeg stops after encoding all of the existent images and has to be run periodically - it doesn't wait for new images

Comment: I can't think of an easy way. You could write a program that simulates an M-JPEG stream using the static images as input. Can you configure the source to send M-JPEG directly?

Comment: I just researched a bit on M-JPEG and it seems pretty useful! thanks for the help!